# Limit the phone to small list of whitelisted apps only (parental control)

Tags: applications, parental-control

Is there a built-in way on Android 9 phones to limit the access to **only a list of specific apps** (for my child)?

Example:

- Phone app
- Camera app
- One or two games
- *No access to Chrome*
- *No access to Facebook*

Is it possible with Android 9's built-in tools, and no third party apps? (or in case an app is needed, I'm looking for a free app without ads)

Comment: There is no built-in way. You could try creating a secondary account and then disable for that account the apps you don't want your child to see. This is tedious and user-unfriendly way. Otherwise, look for a solution involving kiosk mode, app lock, and whatnot.

Comment: @Firelord are you speaking about a secondary account on the same device, or linking to another device which becomes "master" of a slave device? An answer about where (probably hidden in menus, submenus) to create a new account and how to switch to this 2nd account, and how to prevent the child to switch back to the main account (with a key/password?) would be super interesting! Thanks if you know how to do this!

Comment: See this: https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/2865483?hl=en#zippy=%2Cadd-user

Answer (score 0):

You can try Google Family Link App which gives a reasonable informed control over multiple devices.